Minimal angle between Euclidean subspaces
Consider the following minimization problem.  Let $U, V$ be $k$ and $l$ dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively, so that $k+l \leq n$, and $U \cap V = \{\textbf{0}\}$.  Suppose $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equipped with the standard dot product.  Then I wish to find vectors $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ that minimize
$$
\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{u \cdot v}{||u||\cdot||v||}\right).
$$
That is, I wish to find the minimal angle $\theta$ between any pair of vectors $u, v$ in $U$ and $V$, respectively.
This can be set up as an optimization problem.  First, we note that by assumption $U \cap V= \{\textbf{0}\}$, so let $x_1,...,x_k$ be a basis for $U$, and $y_1,...,y_l$ be a basis for $V$.  We then have bases spanning nonintersecting (other than $0$) subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then dropping the $\arccos$ in the above problem (since $\arccos(1)=0$), we wish to minimize the expression
$$
1 - \left(\frac{u \cdot v}{||u||\cdot||v||}\right)
$$
over all vectors $u \in U$, $v \in V$, so expanding by the basis vectors this becomes
$$
1 - \left(\frac{(a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_kx_k)^T \cdot (b_1y_1+\cdots+b_ly_l)^T}{\sqrt{(a_1x_1)^2 + \cdots + (a_kx_k)^2} {\sqrt{(b_1y_1)^2 + \cdots + (b_ly_l)^2}\cdot}}\right)
$$
where we wish to find $a_i$ and $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ that minimize the expression.  Note that it may be that $k \neq l$, and that
Is there in general a way to do this to arbitrary approximation?  Can we effectively find the minimal angle between subspaces (as defined above) like this (i.e. is there an optimization algorithm that can do this to arbitrary accuracy)?

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}$ have columns consisting of orthonormal bases of $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then the optimization problem can be written as
$$\max_{a \in \mathbb{R}^k, b \in \mathbb{R}^l} \frac{a^{\top} X^{\top} Y b}{\sqrt{a^{\top} a}\sqrt{b^{\top} b}}$$
The solution to this optimization problem is the largest singular value of $X^{\top} Y$ by the variational characterization of the SVD.
See also angle between flats.
